# is it safe to open multiple temparay files with mkstemp()

Tags: c

I'm working on an assignment where I'll need to store multiple outputs. This will involve recursion. Will I run into trouble if I have multiple temporary files going using `mkstemp()`?

Comment: What sort of "trouble" are you concerned with? Could you provide more details, please?

Comment: Are you thinking of 1 file per recursion? Oh boy...

Answer (score 1):

You can open as many as you want, up to the limit on the number of open files. Keep in mind that `mkstemp` modifies the string you pass to it in-place, so if you want to keep track of the names to use (or just delete) them later, you need to allocate separate storage for each one. Or if you never need to access them again by name, you could `unlink` them immediately after `mkstemp` returns successfully; then you only need storage for one name.